# The earliest I can arrive in the Schengen with a student visa?

Tags: visas, schengen

Once issued a student visa for the Schengen countries, how many days prior to the course starting will a student typically be allowed in the country? Is it safe to say, 5 days before? I just applied for a visa and of all goes well, it will be issued very, very close to the course start date. I'd like to arrange a ticket beforehand, it would be cheaper to buy now even with change fees then days before I am supposed to leave! Thanks!!

Comment: When you get the visa, it will show a date indicating the beginning of its period of validity.  That's the earliest you can enter the Schengen area.  We cannot predict when you will get the visa nor when that date will be.  This question is receiving close votes because it concerns a student visa and is therefore a better fit for the Expatriates site.  You might consider asking it there, as at least someone might be able to tell you about their own experiences.  That is still likely to have somewhat limited predictive value, however.